# Add hover effect on button for popover only once it has been manually closed

Tags: angular, popover

I am using ngb popovers (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/api) that will display a popover over a button dynamically based on some condition.

Now once that popover is shown (for the first time), I am using some html that allows the user to manually close the popover by clicking on an "x" symbol or it can also be closed with an outside click event (so if user clicks anywhere outside the popover element).

However, if the error still exists, I would like the popover to be shown once hovering over the button (and I am able to do achieve this using triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave" -> https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/examples#delay)

The issue is once the popover is shown for the first time and I hover over the button - it is closed since it triggers the mouseleave event that closes the popover.

I only want the hover affect on the button to be performed once the popover has been manually closed - either through the user doing some outside click event or if they click on the x to forcefully close the popover.

Could someone give me an idea on how to do this please ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To keep the popover open when hovering over the button after it has been manually closed, you can use a combination of the `ngbPopover` directive and the `ngbPopoverManual` input property.

Here are the steps to implement this:

Add a template reference variable to the button that triggers the popover,
for example,

```
#myPopover="ngbPopover".
```

Add the `ngbPopoverManual` input property to the button and bind it to a boolean variable in the component, for example, `ngbPopoverManual="manualClose"`.
In the component, set the `manualClose` variable to true when the popover is manually closed, either by clicking on the "x" symbol or by clicking outside the popover element.

Use the `ngbPopover` directive to display the popover content, and bind the `manualClose` variable to the `ngbPopoverManual` input property.
Use the `mouseenter` trigger to show the popover when hovering over the button, and add a condition to check if the `manualClose` variable is true before showing the popover.

Example:
HTML

```
<!-- Button that triggers the popover -->
<button #myPopover="ngbPopover" ngbPopover="Popover content" ngbPopoverManual="manualClose" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave" (click)="manualClose = false">Show Popover
   <span class="close" (click)="manualClose = true">&times;</span>
</button>
```

// Component code

```
manualClose = false;
```

In this example, the `manualClose` variable is initially set to false. When the popover is manually closed, either by clicking on the "x" symbol or by clicking outside the popover element, the `manualClose` variable is set to true.

The `ngbPopoverManual` input property is bound to the `manualClose` variable, so when the `manualClose` variable is true, the popover will not be displayed.
The mouseenter trigger is used to show the popover when hovering over the button. The (click) event is used to set the `manualClose` variable to false when the "x" symbol is clicked.

Finally, a condition is added to check if the `manualClose` variable is true before showing the popover. This ensures that the popover is only displayed when it has been manually closed.